# How to pass an array to ::with() - Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

So `$permittedTables` is an array of tablenames which I want to join to `coretable`.
To do this, I want to use Model::with(), like so:

```
$join = coretable::with($permittedTables)->get();
```

However, I get this error when executing the above code:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::parseWithRelations() must be of the type array, object given, called in E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1043
```

Whats confusing me the most is the fact this actual IS an array, so I dont really understand why it actually throws THIS error xD

Still, can anyone tell me if this approach is actually possible? And if so, how can I do it?

EDIT:
This is how the array was generated:

```
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findmany($ids)->pluck('extensiontable_name');
```

Just in case this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findmany($ids)->pluck('extensiontable_name');` 
In above code fragment `->pluck()` method returns Object, that's why it throws following error `must be of the type array, object given`

Try using this: `$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findmany($ids)->pluck('extensiontable_name')->toArray()` It should work.

Comment: I am glad to help you. Please accept my answer if not problem

Comment: I will, but stackoverflow makes us wait for another 10 minutes :D before that the system wont let me accept any answer ^^

Answer (score 3):

The [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_pluck) function return Collection/Enumerable, you have to call `toArray` function to get array of table names

```php
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::findmany($ids)
                             ->pluck('extensiontable_name')
                             ->toArray();
```